# SQL varchar datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans, varchar, sqldatatypes

I am using MySQL Adminstrator to create a database

on java netbeans, I created a .php project (a website) which is connected to that database

in the database itself, while creating columns the datatype varchar gives errors .. tried INT(10) and it is working

Any help on how can a datatype be of type short string and long string??

Comment: Show your actual code. What is the error message?

Comment: Not enough information provided in the question. The `VARCHAR` datatype requires a length modifier, e.g. `VARCHAR(10)`. Each storage engine also has a maximum row size. (You say you are "creating" columns, and not modifying an existing column.)  We're really just "guessing" what the problem is. It's not clear why the particular tool you are using to generate/execute SQL statements would produce invalid SQL statement. Your best bet for debugging this issue is to **preview** the actual SQL statement that is going to be issued to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing INT values? If so, just use INT(10) as you used before. If that's not the case, keep in mind that you might need to add quotes inside query due the fact that you are passing a string. Due it like below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

The usage of VARCHAR is correct. You might want to use just CHAR if you know the exact amount of characters needed. If not, VARCHAR is the perfect solution due the fact that a limit is set and it will use only the memory needed according to the string saved.

Comment: MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax. You are getting this error because your query is not well written. Please, show us your query @CodeX

Comment: actually I am not writing queries.. I am using the edit table and edit table data.. in the  edit table i set the datatype of users column  to varchar .. even if it is empty it can not set to varchar .. Thanks btw..

Comment: Another example of a tool getting in the way of using MySQL.